# Radio Boxes in JavaScript and string manipulation

Tags: javascript, html

wondering if anyone can help with my code. I've been trying to get it to work all day and I have no Idea why the code isn't working :(. So the code is supposed to help the user pick a characters in a game to code with 4 questions. The user inputs there answer via radio buttons.

This is the HTML:

```
    <h2> What Champion Should You Play?</h2>
<h3>
    What Lane do You Want to Play?
</h3>
<form onsubmit="getImg()" method="post">
<p> Top </p> <img src="http://img10.deviantart.net/d268/i/2014/226/e/a/gnar__by_dukeofdunkshire-d7v6rgm.jpg"> <input type="radio" name="Lane" value="Top" id="11">
<p> Mid </p><img src="http://www.solomidcdn.com/images/champions/velkoz.png"><input type="radio" name="Lane"  value="Mid" id="12">
<p> Jungle</p><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CF4vu3ZW0AEwR0M.png"><input type="radio" name="Lane" value="Jungle" id="13">
<p> ADC</p><img src="http://img.dwstatic.com/huyaedg/img/hero/Caitlyn.png"><input type="radio" name="Lane" value="Adc" id="14">
<p> Support</p><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2kwycth.png"> <input type="radio" name="Lane" value="Support">


<h3>
    What Role do You Want to Play?
</h3>
   <p>Assassin</p> <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueoflegends/images/3/39/Assassin_icon.jpg/revision/20140607013330"> <input type="radio" name="Role" value="Assasin" id="21">
    <p>Tank</p><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--M5c7oXkX6A/U4_N5v-mLjI/AAAAAAAAQ6g/hduKMsQwSX4/s1600/profileIcon662.jpg"> <input type="radio" name="Role" value="Tank" id="22">
    <p>Bruiser</p><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ZGQQg_79y48/U4-_zTlXL3I/AAAAAAAAQ4g/wnwOyxJ_Ml0/s1600/profileIcon658.jpg"> <input type="radio" name="Role" value="Bruiser" id= "23">
    <p>Marksman</p><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nT8UdY4SZao/U4-_zr_SKQI/AAAAAAAAQ4o/suUj5L2NmFc/s1600/profileIcon660.jpg"> <input type="radio" name="Role" value="Marksman" id= "24">
    <p>Mage</p><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pL_H0M6kCtM/U4-_zXyUA6I/AAAAAAAAQ5A/sFrySjxNBsc/s1600/profileIcon659.jpg"> <input type="radio" name="Role" value="Mage" id="25">

<h3>
    Do You Want to Piss People off with Cheese?
</h3>

<p>Yes</p><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/k/f/l/4/0/cheese-hi.png"> <input type="radio" name="Cheese" value="Yes" id="31">
<p>No</p><img src="http://assets4.tribesports.com/system/challenges/images/000/023/603/original/20120723031440-no-cheese-for-one-week.jpg"> <input type="radio" name="Cheese" value="No" id="32">
<h3>
    Mad Plays or Easy Days?
</h3>
    <p> Mad Plays</p><img src="http://pre12.deviantart.net/4280/th/pre/i/2014/012/3/b/chibi_thresh_by_koiyaki-d71x098.png"><input type="radio" name="Plays" value="Yes" id="41">
    <p> Easy Days</p><img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140807150704/leagueoflegends/images/3/3a/Warwick_Render.png"><input type="radio" name="Plays" value="No" id="42">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

This is the JavaScript, its supposed to get the answer to the radio buttons, If the radio box is checked it adds '1' to the 'pic' string if not it adds '2'. At the end its supposed to open a window with 'pic' in between 2 strings to form a URL. If I put 'window.open' in the first for loop's else bracket it works for the first 5 numbers (opens 4 tabs).

```
    function getImg()
    {
       var radio1 = document.getElementsByName('Lane');
        var radio2 = document.getElementsByName('Role');
        var radio3 = document.getElementsByName('Cheese');
        var radio4 = document.getElementsByName('Plays');
        var pic = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                if (radio1[i].checked) {
                    pic += '1';

                }
                else {
                    pic += '2';

                }
            }
            for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 6; i2++)
            {
                if(radio2[i2].checked)
                {
                    pic += '1';
                }
                else {
                    pic += '2';

                }
            }
        for (var i3 = 0; i3 < 2; i3++)
        {
            if(radio3[i3].checked)
            {
                pic += '1';
            }
            else {
                pic += '2';

            }
        }
        for (var i4 = 0; i4 < 2; i4++)
        {
            if(radio4[i4].checked)
            {
                pic += '1';
            }
            else {
                pic += '2';

            }
        }

            window.open('http://lmetar.com/' + pic + '.png');

    }
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who is able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miscounted the number of radioboxes. Don't count yourself, let the computer do it, that's what they are build for!

```
  function getImg() {
    var radio1 = document.getElementsByName('Lane');
    var radio2 = document.getElementsByName('Role');
    var radio3 = document.getElementsByName('Cheese');
    var radio4 = document.getElementsByName('Plays');
    var pic = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < radio1.length; i++) {
      // shortcut for your if...else construct
      pic += radio1[i].checked ? '1' : '2';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < radio2.length; i++) {
      pic += radio2[i].checked ? '1' : '2';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < radio3.length; i++) {
      pic += radio3[i].checked ? '1' : '2';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < radio4.length; i++) {
      pic += radio4[i].checked ? '1' : '2';
    }
    window.open('http://lmetar.com/' + pic + '.png');

  }
```

The function `document.getElementsByName()` returns a list and you can determine the length of it with `LIST.length`, here: `radioX.length`.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer and for the short cut :)